# Using a standalone ES6 module in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, es6-modules

I have a small ES6 module I wrote that needs to now be integrated into a project that has to support IE11. The rest of the project is written in ES5 and ideally I'd like to just transpile my module and import it as a Script in the project's HTML and have the value it exports attached to the `window` object.

I've tried a few different configurations for babel but they all seemed to be geared towards transpiling a complete bundle of code or required importing polyfills into the original module (which currently has no dependencies), but nothing seems to be compatible with IE11.

Module structure:

```
const MyModule = (() => {
    const moduleStuff = {}
    function moduleLogic(params) {
          doStuff(params)
    }

    return {
        init: initParams => doStuff(initParams),
        moduleMethod: moduleData => {
            doStuff(moduleMethod)
        }
    }
})();

export default MyModule;
```

Comment: You have a brace in 6:4 you should get rid of, then Babel will compile.

Comment: Are you using webpack? If so then the field you want is `output.library` and `output.libraryTarget` https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget

Comment: Babel should do fine to transpile a single file. What target module format did you choose?

Comment: As Federico said, there have an extra brace after the moduleLogic function, after removing it, we could use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) to compile the code,

Comment: Sorry about the typo, I'll edit my question, it's not in the original code, just happened when I was making it generic for the purpose of this example.

The code transpiles fine, the problem is more in getting it to transpile in a way that it can easily be included in the bigger project. I tried several transform plugins to AMD, UMD, CommonJS, etc. but they all seemed to be missing some functionality that made the code throw errors (missing `require` or `exports` variables or some other functions).

Comment: Try to add the following CDN js in the header of Index.html: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.7.4/polyfill.min.js`, more detail information, please check [this link](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone/issues/21).

Answer (score 0):

Not intended to be an answer, but with the link is too long for a comment.

With the typo removed, [seems to look fine to me](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAsgTziAJgVwDYFMYF4YAUBAlHgHwwDeAUDHTKJLALaqZYDKUaAZj3lQC-tejzRhgUAJbgYrdNgAyIAOZTgBAA4BDAE7bmEUjXqn6KEF148teg0ZF1hjmLqzddYKi9NSwUqAAuGD8AgAU7Q3IYCys-AlCoCP1DYgAaH3p5djh3AAtUYOzsABFtKG1okzMa2O544qxcqAKUYkynF2FBYhIAbmpqLAAPTRBdWBQsHm1MWERkBSw-oA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.8.7&externalPlugins=%40babel%2Fplugin-transform-modules-umd%407.8.3)